# Should I make the API a seperate application or a series handlers from my website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, api

I have a personal project with one central application and 3 to 5 clients (a website, iPhone App, Android etc...). I'm trying to focus on .NET on the server.

Should I use ASP.NET MVC 3 for BOTH the website and the API

or

should I have a WCF Project and an A Web Project as two separate solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience with the Microsoft stack, but in the Java world I have used Spring MVC to do both my website and my API using a REST interface. Using REST URLs, the website when viewed in a browser is just one way of viewing the API. If you pass in an accept-encoding request header for XML or JSON, you'll receive your response accordingly.

I would suspect that in most situations, if your API is web based to begin with it's fine to leave it in the same project as your web view, especially for a smaller site. As long as your MVC layer understand the concept of multiple view resolvers, you'll be fine.

Comment: Additionally, what's more important is how you layer the single project. If you create a service layer that is loosely coupled with the rest of the project, it could be externalized later if needed. I have never found a need for that in my experience, however, provided the API is web based.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net MVC is capable enough to support both a API and generate views. With it's JSON and XML ActionResult support ASP.Net MVC can simulate interface similar to WCF. If you design Web application which itself uses the API to access the backend, you can very well use MVC.In case you need some advance capabilities you can always create WCF app and replace the MVC implementation. 
You can create a client library in .Net which can interact with the server, hiding any complexity\difference that arise due to WCF or MVC implementation.

Comment: So if I deploy an MVC site on multiple servers that talk to the same database, will I have any issues??

Comment: I am not sure about your question. But if you talking about horizontal scalability for an app. You app needs to be designed to support such scenarios, this is irrespective the approach you take for API and UI design.